# ModuleNotFoundError on virtual env Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have created a virtual env and installed Jupyter notebood and jupyter lab

after import pandas I get   `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

doing the same operation with `jupyter notebook` does not give me an error, which run in the same venv

I installed pandas into the venv, but got the same error

importing the native python modules works fine

inserting `!pip install pandas` in an empty cell above returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/curwin/jupyterlab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /home/curwin/jupyterlab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /home/curwin/jupyterlab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /home/curwin/jupyterlab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/curwin/jupyterlab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.14.0)
```

Comment: Are you certain jupyter lab and jupyter notebook are running on the same environment? I would also try to install pandas in the notebook where it doesn't find it, by running `!pip install pandas` in an empty cell.

Comment: have tried it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have install a kernel inside the venv with

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=.venv
```

and running notebooks from this kernel solved the problem